# Sharepoint & Excel Advice

Tags: c#, html, excel, sharepoint

Good Morning everyone

I am having some trouble with sharepoint and excel.

Here is my situation:

1. I have a sharepoint site.
2. I have already uploaded an excel workbook containing information in my document library.
3. I want to display the data in excel workbook in like **a table format (Not spreadsheet)** on a page. And the tables **cannot be edited**. This means that when I want to edit something, I have to go to the document library and edit the excel file. Once edit the excel file, the tables at that page will be automatically updated with the latest values.
4. Please help guys  Im really at my wits end now.

Have a good day ahead to all

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the OpenXML 2.0 SDK to open the spreadsheet programmatically and read the data from the spreadsheet and output it using HTML.

Perhaps this article would help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/10/reading-data-from-spreadsheetml.aspx